# When default virtualhost is not available, no virtual hosts are available

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxypass

I have an apache2 instance proxying requests to several tomcat instances.  Sometimes the default virtualhost is unresponsive (tomcat is running but app not responding).  When this happens none of the other virtual hosts are reachable through apache but they work going direct to tomcat.  Should the default virtualhost be a static page to avoid this issue?  Any other settings to tell apache to skip the default if it doesn't respond?

In the `httpd.conf` there are proxypass/proxypassreverse statements outside of the virutalhost blocks.  I don't know if that could be confusing things.

```
ProxyPass /test/ ajp://localhost:9009/test/
ProxyPassReverse /test/ ajp://localhost:9009/test/
ProxyPass /test2/ ajp:/localhost/9010/test2/
ProxyPassRevers /test2/ ajp://localhost:9010/test2/

NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
    ServerName test.domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

...

ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:9009/test/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:9009/test/

...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
ServerName test2.domain.com
ServerAlias test2
PorxyPreseveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
...

ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:9010/test2/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:9010/test2/

...

</VirtualHost>
```

OS: `Solaris 10`
Apache version: `Apache 2.2.6`
Modules: `mod_proxy_ajp`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup a tomcat virtualhost without webapps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342767/how-to-setup-a-tomcat-virtualhost-without-webapps)

Answer (score 1):

It would be suggested to put ProxyPass parameters in VirtualHost section only.